# Color code current day in a calendar

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-calendar

Is it possible to highlight or color code the current day in a calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a "10 Step Guide" to get it working, but it's SharePoint 2013. 
If you still interested you can give it a try.

Works with month, week and dayview!

[10 Steps to get color calendar plus icons - German](https://afrait.com/blog/color-calendar-and-icons-in-10-easy-steps-de/)

[10 Steps to get color calendar plus icons - English](https://afrait.com/blog/color-calendar-and-icons-in-10-easy-steps-en/)

[image]

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Updated the links and added the tutorial in english

Answer (score 1):

The current date is highlighted differently, it is in a div uses the following class: `ms-acal-today`. You could override this style to display something differently. Getting the container with the items for the date a bit more complex. It doesn't have a useful class assoicated with it, for example today on my 2010 calendaer is `ms-acal-day1`.

It would take some jQuery/Javascript to find the date index in the `ms-acal-summary-dayrow` and then get to the proper `ms-acal-summary-itemrow` to do any other stylistic changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a content editor webpart and edit that webpart, Click Edit the source and past the following the CSS.

```
.ms-acal-today{
 color:#0072c6;
}
```

[How to Change the Default Calendar Colors in SharePoint](http://thinketg.com/how-to-change-the-default-calendar-colors-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Hi, the above CSS is being overwritten by a theme.  How can I force my CCS over the theme?

Comment: Solved it with <code><style>
TR TD DIV.ms-acal-today {
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #98ba17
}</style>

Comment: To force a style add !important after the css style. So **color:#0072c6 !important;**